# How to get rid of wrinkles

Tags: modeling

How can I get rid of this wrinkles? Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

[image]

.blend file : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vFLS6B21GgeRlYZSQhvdItLg6IqvyVYz/view?usp=sharing

Comment: you have a lot of ngons, try first to make quads from your ngons

Comment: So ngons are responsible for this wrinkles? Is it always the case? I dissolved some egdes and it seems better now, but it created pinching on other places. Is there some guide for what to watch out when modeling this way so I don't get this issues?

Comment: you can also have problems with quads, but anyway, before everything else, don't keep any ngons

Comment: Ok, and what should I look for where there isn't ngons. Something like splitting quads or?

Answer (score 1):

I think there are too many problem in your topology to be able to answer with few words, for example I see that there is a transversal edge, so I drag up a vertex that is supposed to correct the problem, now I see that you actually had several vertices overlaying, so you need to remove doubles, also you have many ngons, etc...

[image]

For example, if you use the knife tool you can create quads and correct the topology:

[image]